# How to wait for client response with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on an online, turned based game in order to teach myself Node.js and Socket.IO.  Some aspects of the game are resolved serverside.  At one point during one of these functions, the server may require input from the clients.  Is there a way I can "pause" the resolution of the server's function in order to wait for the clients to respond (via a `var x = window.prompt`)?

Here's an idea of the code I'm working with:

Server:

```
for (some loop){
  if (some condition){
   request input via io.sockets.socket(userSocket[i]).emit('requestInput', data)  
  }
}
```

Client:

```
socket.on('requestInput', function (data) {
  var input = window.prompt('What is your input regarding ' + data + '?');
  //send input back to the server
  socket.emit('refresh', input)  
});
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "pause resolution"?

Comment: Maybe "wait" would be the better word.  I'd like for the server's function wait for input from the client before continuing the loop.

Comment: @Cole you can't pause the execution. What you can do is to move everything that should be executed after user input to another function and call it when user responds.

Comment: @fardjad, okay, that is good to know.  I was considering doing that as the next step, but wanted to make sure there wasn't a more obvious solution.

Comment: @hexacyanide Thanks for the formatting fixes--I am very obviously new here.

Comment: Can you please let me know what is the condition used for **for loop*? Chances are you need not need that for loop.. You can start the workflow from the client itself..

Comment: The for loop cycles through the possible conflicts and then (ideally) would shoot out requests for those players to input a bid in an auction before resolving the auction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.

```
for (some loop){
    if (some condition){
    request input via io.sockets.socket(userSocket[i]).emit('requestInput', data) 
    /* Even if you were able to pause the execution here, there is no way to resume   it when client emits the 'refresh' event with user input */
}
```

}

What you can do instead is emit all 'requestInput' events without pausing and save all responses you will get in socket.on('refresh',function(){}) event in an array, then you can process this array later. I don't know what your exact requirement is but let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are emitting `socket.emit('refresh', input)` on the client side, you just need to set up a socket event listener on the server side as well. For example:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('refresh', function (data) {
    console.log(data) //input
  });
})
```

I will also point out, so that you don't run into trouble down the line, that indefinite loops are a big nono in node. Nodejs runs on a single thread so you are actually blocking ALL clients as long as your loop is running.

Comment: Ah, good to know--especially about those loops.  I think I'm realizing that my desire for a workaround was endemic of some bad design in the server-side function and that I should probably do some restructuring.